# Xamarin iOS: What are the document types for OpenOffice and Microsoft Office

Tags: ios, xamarin, uti, document-types

I have a list of microsoft office mime types and office document. Need to find the UTI type for all of them so i can open document picker which only show those documents.

This is my list of the microsoft office I've found, I used them for android, intent filter.

```
"application/msword",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template",
        "application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12",
        "application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12",
        "application/vnd.ms-excel", 
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template",
        "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12",
        "application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12",
        "application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12",
        "application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12",
        "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint", 
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow",
        "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroEnabled.12",
        "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12",
        "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12",
        "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12",
        //Open Office OpenOffice.org2.0, StarOffice 8 and later
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart" ,
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database",
        "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image",
        "application/vnd.openofficeorg.extension",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the most common System UTIs here on Apple documentation here
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html

It doesn't contain all the UTI you're looking for, but I believe you can interchange MS Office UTI with Open office